# Why overload the constructor rather than use methods that return self references?

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

I've just encountered this approach for the first time: using methods which return self-references rather than overloading the constructor. Consider Selenium's [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)'s sample usage:

```
   // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
   // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

The methods `withTimeout`, `pollingEvery`, and `ignoring` each return self references. This seems like a way to bypass having to create an inordinate amount of overloaded constructors. For instance, you would need 2<sup>3</sup>=8 separate overloaded constructor definitions to allow initializing an instance of `FluentWait` with omission or inclusion of the 3 input arguments for timeout, polling, and ignoring. In general, a class whose constructor can have *n* possible input arguments will need to have *2<sup>n</sup>* overloaded constructor definitions (if each possible input combination is desired). Using methods seems like an abridged way to get the same functionality. Why should I not do this all the time? Which scenarios is one approach better than the other?

Comment: [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html) "_Item 1 -  Consider static factory methods instead of constructors_". Available online freely.

Comment: There are multiple patterns and possibilities to create objects and fill them with data. Sometimes one is more appropriate than another. But often it's just personal preference.

Comment: It really depends on the class. Note that your example uses a constructor with arguments too. The constructor takes the mandatory items. The methods take the optional ones. Otherwise the user might create an invalid object since he doesn't know that he must set `setDriver(driver)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite close to [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), please check the overview there for when the pattern is applicable or not.

In this case you say the `FluentWait` returns self-references. It makes the object mutable. This can be problematic if you have multi-threaded or parallel executions.

Comment: Also mutable object might create problem if they used as a key in HashMap

Comment: @ArtemPetrov That's true. There are many other reasons as well, so I'll just leave it with "mutability sucks".

Answer (score 1):

Constructor allows to make fields of the instance `final` which is important for creating immutable object. You also can add checks into the constructor which will validate invariants of your fields. To combine flexibility you like in this approach and benefits of using constructor you can use builder pattern.

Comment: You can create immutable objects in fluent interfaces as well. You only need to create a new instance every time `withSomething` is called. But you're right that it's more natural with builder and constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading constructors and other methods is just a nice way in which you can make use easier for yourself and other developers. Picture that you have an `add()` method. If you want to accept both `2` and `"2"` in Java, you will want to overload your constructor in order to accept both a `String` and `int`.

Like so:

```
public add(String number) {
    ...
}

public add(int number) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking whether using named `static` factory methods has any advantages/disadvantages over ctor overloading.

Comment: That does explain why overloading in general can be useful. But it does not address the specific scenario of OP. He wants to create objects and asks what pattern to use.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I'm not seeing any static factory methods. These are methods that are invoked after the object has been constructed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No he didn't. He asked which way was better to set class variables.

Comment: @Zabuza I agree, I could of made it clearer but seems others have now cleared that up :)

Answer (score 0):

> This seems like a way to bypass having to create an inordinate
>   amount of overloaded constructors.

In fact no it doesn't here as each invoked method returns the current object.
The [javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) states clearly that.
The object is created here : `new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)`

These are fluent invocations.
It avoids prefixing the variable at each time you need to set something in the object.

Instead of writing :

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
wait.setTimeout(30, SECONDS)
wait.pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

You can write :

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                      .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
                      .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
                      .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

There is also fluent builder that is a way to instantiate an object in a fluent and thread-safe way but that is another matter.